# How to Decorate Generic Type field with JsonFormat

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a generic form field class

```
public class FormField<T> {
   private T value;
   private boolean disabled;

   // setters getters are here
}
```

`T` can be `LocalTime` or `LocalDate`.

I would like to provide Jackon Json with proper format depending on what `T` is. Particularly,

if `T` is `LocalDate` I'd like it to behave as 
    `@JsonFormat(... pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")`

If `T` is `LocalTime` I'd like it to be deserialized as `pattern = "HH:mm:ss"`

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom serializable class where you can define different parser for different object type  and use that class with above T generic type with below annotation

```
@JsonSerialize(using=CustomSerializable.class)
private T value;
```